# Sentence construction: Two families or family

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> Chavhan and Khanna **families** invite you to the wedding.

or

> Chavhan and Khanna **family** invite you to the wedding.

Comment: Neither of those is quite right, though to say what it should be requires a little more info. I take it that Chavhan and Khanna are the family names for the families of the two people getting married, but they could conceivably be given names instead.

Answer (score 1):

If there are actually two families involved, then it would be:

> **The** Chavhan and Khanna **families** *invite* you to the wedding.

---

But it's possible that it's a single family—where different people in the family have different last names. If that's the case, then it it would be:

> **The** Chavhan and Khanna **family** *invites* you to the wedding.

---

On the other hand, if Chavhan and Khanna are the first names of the couple getting married, then different constructions would be used:

> **The families of** Chavhan and Khanna *invite* you to the wedding.
>   Chavhan and Khanna's **families** *invite* you to the wedding.